# how to update this viewpager that shows my search result with every search

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a search app for books that get book pictures from a server.
how can I delete the previous search result that has been shown in my viewpager and show a new one?

I tried to set the Viewpageradaptor to null and make another adaptor but it doesn't work and app crashes.

```
 public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context context;
public String data;

 public MyViewPagerAdapter(Context context,Data data) {
    this.context = context;
 //getting url from main activity
    this.data=data;}

  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.object_details_image, collection, false);
    ImageView pagerImage = layout.findViewById(R.id.pagerImage);

     //sending image view to another class to get the image from the internet and  show it in my imageview
     //Downloader is a class that I made to download the images and show them in my Imageview


   new Downloader().showImage(pagerImage ,data);


     collection.addView(layout);
      return layout;
   }

   @Override
 public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object view) {
       container.removeView((View) view);
    }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
   return this.images.size();
   }

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view == object;
}
   }
```

in my Main activity

```
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyViewPagerAdapter(MyApp.getContext(), "image url")
```

Comment: Why do you using viewPager? why not RecyclerView?

Comment: I thought of that .it looks better .i wanted something like what Instagram doing with the collection posts.

Comment: Actually, You can make recylerview scroll horizontally. If you using this manner of course it would be bit different lifecycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every time I wanted to do another search just make a new adapter object.

```
 viewPager.setAdapter(new MyViewPagerAdapter(MyApp.getContext(), "new image url")
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to clear the `this.images` array/List/ArrayList and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` on the viewPager adapter.

if `this.images` is an ArrayList then:

adapter.images.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

if `this.images` is a List then:

```
adapter.images = new ArrayList();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: it deletes the fragments but one fragment that you are currently in, stays in the activity.i made new adaptor object and it worked.